# C# How to store string values in a list outputted from a loop

Tags: c#, arrays, list, .net-6.0

**Q**: How can I capture the data within my `string list`. After it's been looped? Therefore, I can use the list variable elsewhere in my method.

**Goal**: the output to the console needs to contain the value of what it's holding (i.e. the alphabet letters). The function only runs one time. In my progress...my desired/expect outcome almost-occurs when I loop my list a.k.a my string value within a `foreach` loop. However, I only want the output data one time...so a `for` loop is preferable (because it only runs once.)

I believed the simplest way to solve my dilemma is to add another `for loop` to iterate over the existing list. Then print the `index + 1`, and the value at that index to find the solution. But I am having issues.

Expected output (only runs once in a loop)

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
MNO
```

Example Code:

```
var FriendsList = new List<string>();

foreach (var friends in Obj.users)
{
    FriendsList.Add(friend.user);

    foreach (var i in FriendsList)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Undesirable output example:

```
001
001
002
001
002
003
001
002
003
004
001
002
003
004
005
```

I don't believe this to be a good solution

```
//Using Linq to iterate over an array
var Arr = new string[4] {"one", "Two", "Three", "Four"};
Trace.WriteLine(Arr.Select((s, i) => $"Item no: {i + 1}, Value: {s}"));
```

It's wasteful.

I appreciate the help!

Please provide examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you read a value inside **Obj** you print the whole new List **FriendsList** and that's not what you are expecting...

Capturing datas in this way is correct but not the way you wanna print them, you can simply capture them and print **friend** object values.

```
var FriendsList = new List<string>();
foreach (var friend in Obj.users)
{
 FriendsList.Add(friend.user);
 Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", friend, friend.user);
}
```

Otherwise you can use this function after the foreach loop

```
var FriendsList = new List<string>();
foreach (var friend in Obj.users)
{
 FriendsList.Add(friend.user);
}

FrindsList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```